# Reflecting constructors with default values in C#4.0

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, default-value

I've just started using C#4.0(RC) and come up with this problem:

```
class Class1 { public Class1() { } }
class Class2 { public Class2(string param1) { } }
class Class3 { public Class3(string param1 = "default") { } }

Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2), typeof(Class3) };

// Problem starts here, main-method
for(int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
{
    ConstructorInfo ctr = provider.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    Console.WriteLine(ctr == null ? "null" : ctr.Name);
}
```

*Note, I've never tried this actual code, but I've just looked at the results of doing GetConstructor using debugging in VS2010*

This is perfect for the two first classes (1 and 2), the first one prints an actual ConstructorInfo-object's name of the parameterless constructor of Class1, the second prints null. However, the problem arises with the third one, because what I actually want isn't to know whether it takes 0 parameters or not, but it's whether I**can** create an instance of the class without any parameters. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it. It's not pretty but it works.

```
var ctrs = from c in provider.GetConstructors()
           where c.GetParameters().Where(p => !p.IsOptional).Count() == 0
           select c;
ConstructorInfo ctr = ctrs.FirstOrDefault();
```